# How to solve this definite integral $\ln(1+x^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

How to solve this integral: $$\int_{0}^{1} \ln(1+x^n)\,dx.  $$
The problem doesn't say anything about $n$ so I assume $n\in N$.

[Source of the question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TPNK.png)

Comment: From where is this problem?

Comment: It is from an older analysis exam, all it says it's solve this integral.

Comment: $u = \ln(1+x^n), dv = dx, du = \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x^n}dx, v = x$, integrate by parts gives $\ln(2)-n\int_0^1 \frac{nx^n}{x^n+1}dx$. Do $\int_0^1 \frac{nx^n}{x^n+1}dx = \int_0^1 \frac{nx^n+n-n}{x^n+1}dx = n-n\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^n+1}dx$. So all you need to do is $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^n+1}dx$.

Comment: Mathematica yields the incredibly ugly $$-\Phi(-1,1,1+1/n)+\ln(2), $$
if $\operatorname{Re}[(-1)^{1/n}]\ge 1$ or $\operatorname{Re}[(-1)^{1/n}]\le 0$ or  $(-1)^{1/n}\not\in\mathbb{R}.$ Also, $n>0.$ Here $\Phi$ is the Hurwitz-Lerch transcendent function.

Comment: I would bet that there should have been a limit in front of that integral.

Comment: @mathworker21: The remaining integral there is highly non-trivial, involving the PolyGamma function.

Comment: $$\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\frac{(x^n)^k}{k}dx=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k}\int_0^1x^{nk}dx=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k(1+kn)}=\log (2)-\Phi \left(-1,1,1+\frac{1}{n}\right),$$ the last part via partial fractions.

Comment: @Zacky Well... I double checked, there isn't.

Comment: @Adrian Keister I've used the gamma and theta functions before but only for simple stuff. I will try to get that to gamma form tomorrow, thank you all for the answers.

Comment: @Florin1335 but do you have the original problem? Maybe a photo with it? // Things like:
$\lim\limits _{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 \ln(1+x+x^n)dx$ and so on are quite standard for exams I would say.

Comment: @Zacky [link](https://imgur.com/3E2lVMK) What can I say half of the exam is theory and then he comes up with stuff like this.

Comment: @Florin1335 thanks for the photo! Well, I still believe there's just a typo and the teacher forgot to add the limit. There is no way one would ever mark this integral the same points as for proving that $\ln(1+x)\le x$. In particular I think that inequality was given in order to show (followed by squeezing the limit):
$$\int_0^1 \ln(1+x^n)dx\le \int_0^1 x^n dx=\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Comment: @Zacky You are probably right, thank you. Now I think I should remove this question...

Comment: In the integrand, replace $x$ with $1-x$, then expand $(1-x)^n$ using binomial theorem. The property here is that $\int_0^a f(x)dx=\int_0^a f(a-x)dx$.

Comment: @Zacky: I have provided more of an answer than I would normally (due to scarcity of context), but since the source is given and the question shown there is possibly out of the scope of the other problems, I think it is safe to answer this question fully, if only to show the complexity of the answer to the stated question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplifying $\prod\limits_{k\neq j=0}^{n-1}\frac1{\lambda_{n,k}-\lambda_{n,j}}$ for $\lambda_{n,k}=\exp\frac{i\pi(2k+1)}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3144672/simplifying-prod-limits-k-neq-j-0n-1-frac1-lambda-n-k-lambda-n-j)

Comment: @robjohn was the ping meant for OP instead of me? // In my opinion I think it's a good thing what you did. OP in particular provided the source and colaborated in comments a lot. He didn't show what he tried, but given the problem one can easily understand why.

Comment: It was meant as a comment on the question, but some was for the OP. I didn't think I had addressed it to anyone; sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Prelude with Harmonic Numbers**
$$
\begin{align}
H(x)&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+x}\right)\tag1\\
\frac12H\!\left(\frac x2\right)&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{2k}-\frac1{2k+x}\right)\tag2\\
H(x)-H\!\left(\frac x2\right)&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+x}\right)\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: extension of the [Harmonic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) to $\mathbb{C}$
$(2)$: compute the series for even indices
$(3)$: compute the alternating series

The Harmonic numbers are related to the [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) by $H(x)=\gamma+\psi(1+x)$, where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

---

**The Integral**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\log\left(1+x^n\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^1\frac{(-1)^{k-1}x^{nk}}k\,\mathrm{d}x\tag4\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k(nk+1)}\tag5\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1/n}\right)\tag6\\[3pt]
&=H\!\left(\frac1n\right)-H\!\left(\frac1{2n}\right)\tag7\\[6pt]
&=\psi\!\left(1+\frac1n\right)-\psi\!\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right)\tag8
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(4)$: apply the Taylor series for $\log(1+x)$
$(5)$: evaluate the integrals
$(6)$: partial fractions
$(7)$: apply $(3)$
$(8)$: give $(7)$ in terms of the Digamma function

Note that using $(7)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2235362), we can compute $(7)$ as a finite sum in terms of logs, sines, and cosines.

Comment: Or just apply [Gauss's digamma theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Gauss's_digamma_theorem) at the end.

Comment: Which hopefully gives the same answer as $(7)$.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating by parts as suggested by [mathworker21](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3343358/how-to-solve-this-definite-integral-ln1xn#comment6881792_3343358) gives

\begin{align}\int\ln(1+x^n)~\mathrm dx&=x\ln(1+x^n)-n\int\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}~\mathrm dx\\&=x\ln(1+x^n)-n\int\frac{1+x^n-1}{1+x^n}~\mathrm dx\\&=x\ln(1+x^n)-nx+\int\frac n{1+x^n}~\mathrm dx\end{align}

where the last bit is given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1999967/272831) as a combination of logarithms and arctangents, provided $n\in\mathbb Z$. In a similar manner, rational $n$ can be handled as well. In the case of irrational $n$, one requires special functions, such as the digamma function.